STM32 - compile in debug and release mode - can it be done per file?
Maybe a stupid question - but I searched cand couldn't find a good solution...
I'm running into an issue with memory on my STM32 project.
Is there a way to compile all files in release mode (smaller hex file size) except for the one I want to debug on / put breakpoints?
Or how can I develop on a project, that uses the full available memory, while still being able to debug it?

That's not a question about STM32, but related to some process how you compile your project or source code. The only answer to that is obviously "yes" but we don't know how you compile your project and source code.

Yes, you can do that.
"Release" and "debug" versions commonly differ mainly in the optimization level. For your goal it does not matter that the linker's output includes more symbols in the "debug" version, because the resulting (and size limited) machine code does not include any symbol.
You can compile each module with different options. This includes specifically the optimization level.
With better optimization compilers commonly do "funny" things to the resulting binary, which leads to unexpected effects when single stepping through your code. If you accept this fact, you can even debug a "release" build.
Just some examples:

Similar statement sequences are merged, so single stepping seems to jump around randomly.
Statements are divided, merged, or re-ordered.
Loops are unrolled or optimized away.
Variables are optimized away, so you cannot see their values.
Multiple variables are mapped into the same memory or processor register, which leads to unexpected values changes in watched variables after the last access to them.

Your next step is to understand how your development environment works, and how to control it.
